# Finding height of the triangle

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

It is known that the area of the triangle COA is $$\triangle COA = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot \tan(x)$$

But I can't figure out how $$\mathrm{AC}=\tan(x)$$ was derived.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note

$$|OM| = |OA| = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

due to both line segments are radii of the unit circle. Since $\triangle OAC$ is a right-angled triangle with $\measuredangle OAC = 90^{\circ}$, you have $\tan$ of an angle being the length of the opposite side over the length of the adjacent side, so you get

$$\tan x = \frac{|AC|}{|OA|} = |AC| \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

From this, using that the area of a right-angled triangle is one-half of the product of the base and the height, i.e., of the $2$ non-hypotenuse sides, you get what you stated at the question start, i.e.,

$$A(\triangle COA) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot |OA|\cdot |AC| = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 \cdot \tan x \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$